# Adjusting font-weight:bold

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using `{font-weight:bold}` for an Arial font, but it seems to be too thick. Can  I make things a little thinner? I cant find any other method to do it. I've used {font-weight:400} - Specifying in increments of 100. But it's the same thing. Too thick. Any other way to make a font a bit bolder than the other text?

Comment: Why not choose a different font?

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @EdHeal It'll look kinda odd. Everything else on the body is Arial.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert I'm tesing on Chrome and FireFox. It's even more thicker on IE9

Comment: @norman - Just use the appropriate font for the whole of it. The one that gives you the desired effect (or perhaps live with it as it depends on the OS/Screen/Browser/Zoom etc)

Comment: It completely depends on the font. If Arial is not available in the weights you need, consider trying a different one. Helvetica seems to have quite a few weights.

Comment: Show us minimal HTML code you are using. Maybe you have `B` or `STRONG` element inside element that has `font-weight: bold` — Firefox generates sort of faux Black font-weight in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many many many fonts that look like Arial that you can play with , some are bolder then others ,

Try looking for a font [In Google WebFonts](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/getting_started) and you can attach it into your css to ensure it will work in every browser

Comment: Browsers do let you choose a halfway point between bold (700 weight) and normal (300 weight), but only if the font itself has those in-between weights.  Using a font with a good variety of weights from Google WebFonts is a good suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert - sorry _ you're right , I meant half-way between font-weight:400 and normal

Comment: Yes go to Google webfonts or fontsquirrel.com and look for fonts with more than 2 styles. Just 2 styles is usually regular and italic. Fonts with more styles than that are usually those with a variety of weights.

Comment: edited answer , google web fonts should have something useful

Answer (score 1):

The Arial font has no typeface with a weight between normal (400) and bold (700). Some other fonts do. So you might choose a different that either has an in-between weight or has a bold typeface that suits you needs and eye.

For example, the Google fonts [Source Sans Pro](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro) and [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans) are more or less similar to Arial, and both of them have a semi-bold (600) typeface.

It is possible to create sort-of fake bolding of different degrees using text shadowing, with the color being the same as text color, in CSS, e.g. `text-shadow: 1px 0 black`. But the result is poor. Genuine bolding is rather different from such artificial thickening of strokes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man, but Arial Bold is not too thick as you say, It's just "Bold". (Arial Black or Alfa Slab is what then?). But if YOU feel it's too thick for you, you can try a webFont that have a light style and then you can use the regular one as as your Bold style.